# In Perl, how can I output the diagonal of the Cartesian product of a set with itself before all the off-diagonal elements?

Tags: perl

I want to output all the combinations of two letters, but I want the combinations between the same letters to be shown first. Basically, I want to get something like this:

If I have

```
@list = ("A", "B", "C")
```

I want my output to be:

```
AA  -
BB  -
CC  -
AB
AC
BA
BC
CA
CB
```

Normally, if I'd just use two for loops I'd get

```
AA  -
AB
AC
BA
BB  -
BC
CA
CB
CC  -
```

Is there any fast (easy to understand / simple) way to get the output as I want?

Comment: Nope if you want to print all combinations you cant have faster than O(N!) algorithm

Comment: I want to print all the combinations. By fast, I'm not referring to the time complexity. I meant if there is an easy to understand method to do it, without too much hassle. Thank you for the edit btw :P

Comment: You might enjoy trying to get your head round the `permute` sub on [Perl monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=24270). If you count that as easy to understand, then good for you!

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like what I'm looking for, but it might set me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: 1) Is the size of `@list` variable? 2) If it's is, is the desired output still a list of pairs?

Comment: The size of the list is variable. The output should be a list of pairs, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for my $e (@list) {
    say $e.$e;
}

for my $i (0..$#list) {
    for my $j (0..$#list) {
        say $list[$i].$list[$j] if $i != $j;
    }
}
```

It should meet your requirements as it's 3 times faster than previously presented solutions<sup>[1]</sup>, yet it's still quite clear.

---

1. There was a benchmark in another answer, but it got deleted.

Comment: I thought you asked if there was a *faster* way, but you merely asked for a *fast* way. Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about my English skills, some words in my native language don't quite gain the same meaning when translated into English. Initially I was searching for an answer that I can easily understand. Even if it is a very good piece of code, I can't really appreciate it if I can't wrap my head around it. Sinan's original answer is good (the edited version is even better and offers a chic alternative), but I have to agree more with ikegami's solution. It's pretty simple and judging from the benchmarks, more efficient. But I want to thank you both for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Look, I don't know what's going on between you two, but please stop editing each others' answers. You have a better solution? Write it in your answer and leave the other person alone.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, You've been admonished for making these off-topic and incorrect comments in my answer, but they are no better as comments to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This has already been addressed, but I think the simplest solution is just to handle your special case in custom code and then rely on the standard modules for everything else.

For combinatoric modules, can use either [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm%3a%3aCombinatorics) or [`Math::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aCombinatorics).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations_with_repetition);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @set = ('A'..'C');
my $length = 3;

# Trivial Diagonal Solutions
for my $element (@set) {
    my @solution = ($element) x $length;
    print "@solution\n"
}

# All Other Solutions
my $iter = variations_with_repetition(\@set, $length);
while (my $p = $iter->next) {
    next if 1 == uniq @$p;
    print "@$p\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easier way than:

```
@letters = ( 'A', 'B' );
@list = ( $letters[0].$letters[0], $letters[1].$letters[1], $letters[0].$letters[1], $letters[1].$letters[0] );
```

Comment: True, but that is for just two letters. It would be quite the hassle if I'd add a few more.

Comment: @user3433676: your definition of the desired order doesn't extend to more than two.  if you have a more general question, please update your question and explain how you want them ordered?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (glob("{A,B,C}{A,B,C}")) {
  print;
  print " -" if /(.)\1/;
  print "\n";
}
```